# The New Artscroll Mishnayos: Product Recommendation

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, mishna, artscroll

In addition to their (rather expensive and extremely expansive) Yad Avraham series, Artscroll is now publishing a Schottenstein Edition of the Mishna.

Both versions (Yad Avraham and Schottenstein) exist in a Hebrew edition as well as in an English edition.

I have been using the English Schottenstein Edition of the Talmud Bavli lately, and find that it has been of inestimable value in improving my study (and chazorah) of gemara. Has anybody here used either of these Artscroll Mishna commentaries?

What I would like is (if at all possible) a comprehensive breakdown of Artscroll's "Mishnayos", for the purposes of comparison. Are they comprehensive? Easy to read? Easy on the eyes?

Effectively, would you recommend one of them over the other, and why?

Comment: If you go to the Artscroll website, you could use their 'Look Inside' feature to see what the books look like. Here's the link for the Schottenstein Mishna: https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422619940.html

Answer (score 10):

I have learned the entire Mishna based on the Yad Avraham series in English. I also own much of the newer Schottenstein Edition of the Mishna. Here are a few thoughts

- I found the introductions to each tractate to be incredibly well done and useful. Just reviewing the introductions to all tractates would be in itself wonderful learning. I compared the introductions to Brachot and it is somewhat more detailed in the Yad Avraham edition
- The commentary in the Yad Avraham edition is very very very (!) detailed. It was too much for me when learning the text but is obviously what you want if you are interested to go in depth in certain places
- The translation between both is very different. Yad Avraham translates the English "in one go", like the Stone Chumash does, while Schottenstein has the literal translation a few words, then a few words of explanation to make it a running text, then again literal translation. Exactly as the elucidation of the Talmud Bavli you refer to. The latter (Schottenstein) is far more readable and avoids to constantly need to refer to the notes
- The Yad Avraham has 44 volumes, the new Schottenstein has 21. In the introduction to Schottenstein, artscroll themselves address the difference between them. They write

> The Yad Avraham is an encyclopedic, in-depth commentary that presents
>   many explanations and explores nuances and complexities, raises
>   questions and cites a wide variety of works on the Mishnah and Talmud.
>   Its thoroughness has won the praise of even masters of the Talmud
>   throughout the world so that those who study and benefit from the
>   Schottenstein edition may turn to the Yad Avraham commentary when they
>   wish to delve into the nuances of the Mishna more deeply and explore a
>   wider range of comments. Thus, in effect, the two editions complement
>   each other

When I learn the Mishna again from beginning to the end, I plan to use the Schottenstein edition.

Finally, note that

- I bought the "[personal size](http://search.artscroll.com/Books/9781422610800.html)" (small size) full set which retails for 500$ but can regularly be bought at an additional discount of 10-20% when artscroll runs a sale. You can also buy one order of the mishna now to start learning and buy the others when the discounts start
- The Schottenstein is about 30% cheaper (4 sets of Zeraim, Moed, Nezikin, Nashim are about 200$ vs 290$ for Yad Avraham)

Comment: Wonderful answer - thank you so much. Did you find that the pages continued to hold together nicely after so much use? (Often small, pocket-sized, soft-cover books fall apart in my experience.) It looks like Yad Avraham might be what I'm looking for: first time I finished the Mishna it was with Kehati, but I need something that helps me go deeper (and improves my chazorah). I think this might be it!

Comment: @ShimonbM I just checked and they are all in impeccable shape. Since there is a booklet per masechet, each of them is quite small and therefore there is less pressure on the spine

Comment: +1 I know the question didn't ask for it, but do you by any chance have any experience with the Kehati commentary and how it compares to each of these two? Just to make this answer fully comprehensive regarding modern Mishna editions.

Comment: @DoubleAA not as much - and I do not know if it is available in English. I have it in Hebrew, and it is much more concise, but I haven't studied it thoroughly

Comment: Feldheim puts out an English version. I personally have more experience with that one than either artscroll edition

Comment: @DoubleAA I think Kehati is very easy, but he generally avoids to address difficult parts, even if it is necessary for a valuable minimal pshat.

Comment: @DoubleAA Years ago in comparing Kehati & Yad Avraham (the newer Artscroll didn't exist yet), my chavruta and I found we far preferred Yad Avraham to Kehati.  As kouty notes, Kehati sometimes leaves out important information.  As an example, my chavruta noted in a mishna discussing bones that are most of a person but still less than a kezayit, Kehati never says how this is possible, but YA says it is from a neonate or even a fetus.