# Teaching Gemara to a beginner to prepare for yeshiva. Goal is basic fluency. Looking for a simple perek/masechet to learn. Thanks!

Tags: talmud-gemara, torah-study, chinuch-education

He's a senior in high school and a very smart, analytical fellow though he lacks some basic textual skills because he's in public school. Going for gap year yeshiva next year and they said he should get basic fluency reading/understanding Gemara.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Nitay and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: possibly helpful: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/138104/11501

Answer (score 2):

B"H

Usually children begin learning Gemara with the chapter אלו מציאות, in Bava Metzia.

While it is actually quite complex, as is any chapter in Gemara when learned with more depth and concentration, it is still considered one of the standard "simple" chapters that kids start learning Gemara with.
Another beginner chapter is  הכונס צאן, in Bava Kamma, as well.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: A good reason to choose אלו מציאות is that it has many repetitions of similar phrases, which allows the student to gain momentum in their reading. It's difficult for new students when they need to ask about every word in a sentence, so when there are sentences made up of phrases that they learned in the beginning of the lesson, they can actually focus on learning the style of logic and feel like they are accomplishing something, instead of getting caught on the language barrier.